# Why does clang's epilogue use `add $N, %rsp` instead of `mov %rbp, %rsp` to restore `%rsp`?

Tags: assembly, clang, x86-64, micro-optimization

Consider the following:

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ vi test.c
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ cat test.c

extern void use_buffer(void *buf);

void a_func(void)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    use_buffer(buffer);
}

__asm__("emit_mov_rbp_to_rsp:\n\tmovq %rbp, %rsp");

ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ clang -Wall -Wextra -c -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer test.c -o test.o
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <emit_mov_rbp_to_rsp>:
   0: 48 89 ec              mov    %rbp,%rsp
   3: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00  cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   a: 00 00 00 
   d: 0f 1f 00              nopl   (%rax)

0000000000000010 <a_func>:
  10: 55                    push   %rbp
  11: 48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
  14: 48 81 ec 00 10 00 00  sub    $0x1000,%rsp
  1b: 48 8d bd 00 f0 ff ff  lea    -0x1000(%rbp),%rdi
  22: e8 00 00 00 00        call   27 <a_func+0x17>
  27: 48 81 c4 00 10 00 00  add    $0x1000,%rsp
  2e: 5d                    pop    %rbp
  2f: c3                    ret    
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$
```

At the end of `a_func()`, before return, it's the function epilogue that restores `%rsp`. It uses `add $0x1000, %rsp` which yields `48 81 c4 00 10 00 00`.

Can't it just use `mov %rbp, %rsp` which only yields 3 bytes `48 89 ec`?

Why clang doesn't use the shorter way (`mov %rbp, %rsp`)?

With code size trade-off, what is the advantage of using `add $0x1000, %rsp` instead of `mov %rbp, %rsp`?

#### Update (extra)

Even with `-Os`, it still results in the same code. So I think there must be a rational reason to avoid `mov %rbp, %rsp`.

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ clang -Wall -Wextra -c -Os -fno-omit-frame-pointer test.c -o test.o
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <emit_mov_rbp_to_rsp>:
   0:   48 89 ec                mov    %rbp,%rsp

0000000000000003 <a_func>:
   3:   55                      push   %rbp
   4:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   7:   48 81 ec 00 10 00 00    sub    $0x1000,%rsp
   e:   48 8d bd 00 f0 ff ff    lea    -0x1000(%rbp),%rdi
  15:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1a <a_func+0x17>
  1a:   48 81 c4 00 10 00 00    add    $0x1000,%rsp
  21:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  22:   c3                      ret    
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's using RBP as a frame pointer at all, yes, `mov %rbp, %rsp` would be more compact and AFAIK at least as fast on all x86 microarchitectures.  (mov-elimination probably even works on it).  Even moreso when the add constant doesn't fit in an imm8.

This is probably a missed optimization, very similar to https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10319 (which proposes using `leave` instead of mov/pop, which would cost 1 extra uop on Intel but save another 3 bytes).  It points out the overall static code size savings are pretty small in normal cases, but isn't considering efficiency benefits.  In normal builds (`-O2` without `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`) only a few functions will use a frame pointer at all (only when using VLA / alloca, or over-aligning the stack) so the possible benefit is even smaller.

It seems from that bug that it's just a peephole the LLVM doesn't bother to look for, because many functions also need to restore other registers, so you actually need to `add` some other value to point RSP below other pushes.

(GCC sometimes uses `mov` to restore call-preserved regs so it can use `leave`.  With a frame pointer, that makes the addressing mode fairly compact to encode, although a 4-byte qword `mov -8(%rbp), %r12` is still not as small as 2-byte pop of course.  And if we don't have a frame pointer (e.g. in `-O2` code), `mov %rbp, %rsp` was never an option.)

---

Before considering the "not worth looking for" reason, I thought of another minor benefit:

After calling a function that saves/restores RBP, RBP is a load result.  So after `mov %rbp, %rsp`, future use of RSP would need to wait for that load.  Possibly some corner cases end up bottlenecked on store-fowrwarding latency, vs. register modification just being 1 cycle.

But that seems unlikely to be worth the extra code size in general; I expect such corner cases are rare.  Although that new RSP value is needed for a `pop %rbp`, so then the caller's restored RBP value is the result of a chain of two loads after we return.  (Fortunately `ret` has branch prediction to hide latency.)

So it might be worth trying both ways in some benchmarks; e.g. comparing this vs. a tweaked version of LLVM on some standard benchmarks like SPECint.

Comment: Thanks, it seems we have the duplicate of this https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10319

Comment: I would have expect the answer to be, "because then you can use RBP as an extra register".  (Obviously the compile has to emit offsets from RSP rather than RBP, but that's technically straightforward).

Comment: @IraBaxter: This is compiled using `clang -Os -fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  People want that sometimes (and IIRC is the `-Os` GCC default), so if you're already forcing the compiler to waste RBP on being a frame pointer, you want to get maximum benefit out of it.   But yeah, since you mention it, tweaked the phrasing to remind readers that most software is built without `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.)